# reset texture paint brushes?

Tags: texture-painting

I have looked online in other places, but I can't find any results relating to this. I have installed a new version of blender and loaded my file without the keep ui checked, but no luck.
So, I will be working on a file for a while, and one of my texture paint brushes will turn into a regular texture paint brush. (In this case, my smear brush) and I have no way of resetting it or changing the settings to get my smear brush back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brush settings are loaded even if the Load UI option is disabled. The brush type can be adjusted in the brush menu, so if you have deleted the brush you can create a new brush and set it to smear.

[image: brush options]

You can import brushes from another file so to restore the default brushes without changing any of your other settings, choose *File->Load Factory Settings*, then save the blend file somewhere, then create a new file to get your normal settings back and import the brushes from the factory file you just saved and re-save your startup file.

Comment: i eventually used the import method, however its nice to know there is a ui driven fix for this. i would expect this to be in the viewport's brush ui, rather than the image editor, but i guess it cant be helped. where can i suggest changes to the blender foundation?

Comment: That's the header of the 3d viewport but it is also in the image editor when painting. Not really an option that would get changed a lot so doesn't need to be prominent. If you change the python script yourself you could submit a patch to [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/) or submit a suggestion at [right-click select](https://rightclickselect.com) for someone else to do it.